# AngularJS Bootstrap Tooltip - trigger on event

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm looking into the Angular Bootstrap UI tooltip, what i'd like to do is show the tool tip not on focus, or blur, but when I click a button. I know i can do this with a provider, but it's not clear how. I'd like to do this without Javascript or JQuery if possible, as i'm sure there's an Angular way :)

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module("ngSignupPage", ['ui.bootstrap'])
        .controller("signUpController", function($scope) {      
            $scope.tooltipMessage = 'Hola mundo!';          
            $scope.showTooltip = function(){
                //  I'd like to show the tooltip with a custom message here
            };
        });
})();

<form name="signupForm" noValidate ng-submit="showTooltip()">
     <input 
        type="text" 
        tooltip="{{tooltipMessage}}" 
        tooltip-trigger="focus" /* Can i set this when 'showTooltip' is clicked? */
        tooltip-placement="bottom" />
    <button>Save</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Here's a better solution without Jquery using a directive to fire the customEvent.

On your app config you add the custom trigger:

```
.config(['$tooltipProvider', function($tooltipProvider){
  $tooltipProvider.setTriggers({'customEvent': 'customEvent'});
}]);
```

Html:

```
<div fire-custom-event>
  <span tooltip-html-unsafe="My <em>fancy</em> tooltip" tooltip-trigger="customEvent">Target for a tooltip</span>
  <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('fireCustomEvent', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.find('button').on('click', function () {
                element.find('span').trigger("customEvent");
            });
        }
    };
});
```

[Check the demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/07W3ApSfStSVflJvbAcz?p=preview)

**FIRST ANSWER**

On your app config you can add a custom trigger:

```
.config(['$tooltipProvider', function($tooltipProvider){
  $tooltipProvider.setTriggers({'customEvent': 'customEvent'});
}]);
```

And then in you controller you can fire the event. Unfortunately you need JQuery to do this:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', ['$scope','$timeout',
function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.fireCustomEvent = function() {
      $timeout(function() {
        $('#tooltipTarget').trigger('customEvent');
      }, 0);
    }
}]);
```

[Check this demo here](http://plnkr.co/edit/16DUNyq4N1ZIps2EFv1x?p=preview)

Comment: Perfect, that gets my head around the providers perfectly :) thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately the updated answer still relies on jquery