# AngularJS Bootstrap Popover custom trigger

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

In my WebApp I want to show a customized popover that will be triggered when a variable in my controller is set. To achieve this I've created a custom trigger event and set it with `$tooltipProvider.setTriggers({"showChat": "hideChat"}]`

Here is a [plnkr.co](http://plnkr.co/edit/vbaxzWIHUl6adKzucBJy) of my code that does not working.

I also checked other solutions here on StackOverflow (like [AngularJS Bootstrap Tooltip - trigger on event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29525689/angularjs-bootstrap-tooltip-trigger-on-event) or [Good way to dynamically open / close a popover (or tooltip) using angular, based on expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20939754/good-way-to-dynamically-open-close-a-popover-or-tooltip-using-angular-based)) that seem to work, but I can't figure out where my code is wrong.
I assume it's just a little thing (like always.. :-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular-bootstrap seems to use addEventListener to subscribe to this event, which means you cannot trigger it with .trigger(), what you'll need is dispatchEvent:

```
if(scope.showPopover) {
  console.log('trigger showChat')
  element.get(0).dispatchEvent(new Event("showChat"));
} else {
  console.log('trigger hideChat')
  element.get(0).dispatchEvent(new Event("hideChat"));
}
```

See in this fixed [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/eS7LowiA27LF0oqnBhfw?p=preview).

Btw: unless you do something more complicated in your app, you can simply use `popover-is-open="showPopover"` to trigger the popover, like in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GbImfgfXD9XKooV0bTSy?p=preview)